Etherscan does not lists transactions
Maybe someone knows why Etherscan does not display this transaction and other similar transactions for this contract in the transaction list, while it can still be seen as a single transaction specifically for that contract.
By the way, this is some kind of oracle callback, and it's a proxy contract.
Transaction Link: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc72bed0224607dbf967a424de6ef09bdff8b65e08df4a7cd3149cd607e63ba79
Contract Address Link: https://etherscan.io/address/0x0a0f4321214bb6c7811dd8a71cf587bdaf03f0a0

I can see the transaction clearly, but I'm not sure where you're trying to find it.

This is a 52-day-old transaction, which means you'll have to visit the past transactions.
You can click on this "view all transactions" and go through them to find it.


yes you are right, somehow i missed that this trx was old, got confused it was recent. thnx
